# UITableView setContentInset large value animates slowly

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview with another view (called `bottomView`) as a subview placed at the bottom of the content of the tableview. What I want to happen is, when the user pulls up when at the very bottom of the tableview, upon release I want to slide the tableview up so that `bottomView` appears. To do this, I implement the delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate: (BOOL)decelerate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 250, 0)];
    }];
}
```

(250 is the height of bottomView) in an animation block. What I expect to happen is for the tableview to slide up 250pts, revealing the `bottomView`. Oddly enough, what ends up happening is that the table only slides up a little bit (maybe 100pts) and does so very slowly, over around 5 seconds, when my animation block was only for .1 seconds.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this , hope this helps

```
  -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   {
        aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 250, 0);
   }
   -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   {
        UIEdgeInsets insects =  aTableView.contentInset;
        if(insects.top == 0)
         {
            aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 250, 0);
            CGSize size = aTableView.contentSize;
            int height = size.height;
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                 aTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, height-250);
             }];
             aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
         }

   }

  -(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
  {
      if(!decelerate)
       {
          UIEdgeInsets insects =  aTableView.contentInset;
         if(insects.top == 0)
         {
           CGSize size = aTableView.contentSize;
           int height = size.height;
              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
           aTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, height-250);
              }];
           aTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
         }
      }
  }
```

adjust the contentOffset according to requirement

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately, this had no apparent effect on my tableview.

Comment: did u added that bottomView to table footer view

Comment: I modified according to what you mentioned after user scrolls up or down you want always display that bottom view rite. I checked with this, i added a view of 250 px height to table footer view it scrolls perfectly when user scrolls up.